# bower command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I tried to install twitter bower on my Mac, and I used

```
npm install bower -g
```

Then I tried `bower --help`, and the output was `bower command not found`. Why is that?

Comment: What is the output from `npm install`? Did it fail? Did it install bower to some location not on your `PATH`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["command not found" after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation)

Comment: Related posts - [bower is not recognised as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27360710/465053) & [bower command not found windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21732447/465053)

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Just like in this question ([npm global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix)) all you need is to set proper `npm prefix`.

**UNIX:**

```
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower

$ which bower
>> /usr/local/bin/bower
```

**Windows ans NVM:**

```
$ npm config set prefix /c/Users/xxxxxxx/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v8.9.2
$ npm install -g bower
```

Then `bower` should be located just in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I would like to add that this is not the most correct answer if you work with multiple projects. Bower should be installed in the `node_modules`locally from `package.json` and not globally, since different projects can use different versions (that's the whole point of `npm`). The real problem is that the system is not able to find the local bower executable.

Comment: @BrunoFinger: When installing bower to global scope, that answer is not solving the problem. However using local node packages might be a better way of dealing with project specific tools.

Comment: I think if npm prefix is set to /usr/local, npm install -g will fail without sudo.

Comment: We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel.

Answer (score 66):

I am almost sure you are not actually getting it installed correctly. Since you are trying to install it globally, you will need to run it with sudo:

```sh
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Comment: That is how bower must be installed, otherwise it will be just installed on the folder where you executed the command. -g means global and it also creates the required links for modules that can be executed as system commands, bower, grunt-cli, even npm are clear examples of this.

Comment: Dont install with sudo!   Just use brew doctor and make the fixes that brew doctor suggests and then you wont need to use sudo!

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use `npx` which comes along with the npm > 5.6.

`npx bower install`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You shouldn't ever install global modules with npm.

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to NOT be a bower problem, though it showed up for me with bower.

It seems to be a node-which problem. 
If a file is in the path, but has the setuid/setgid bit set, which will not find it.

Here is a files with the s bit set: (unix 'which' will find it with no problems).

> ls -al /usr/local/bin
>       -rwxrwsr-- 110 root    nmt  5535636 Jul 17  2012 git

Here is a node-which attempt:

```
> which.sync('git')
Error: not found: git
```

I change the permissions (chomd 755 git).
Now node-which can find it.

```
> which.sync('git')
'/usr/local/bin/git'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am using node version manager. I was getting this error message because I had switched to a different version of node. When I switched back to the version of node where I installed bower, this error went away. In my case, the command was `nvm use stable`