# npm global path prefix

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, zsh

I am being more cautious than usual because I have been confused by the behavior of `npm` in the past.

I am on a Mac and have installed node.js through `brew install node`.

Now that I want to run `jslint.js` on the command-line as the command `jslint` I find that the canonical way to accomplish this is `sudo npm install -g jslint` which ran successfully with this output:

```
$ sudo npm install -g jslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint/-/jslint-0.1.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint/-/jslint-0.1.9.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-l.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.4.tgz
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/jslint -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/jslint/
bin/jslint.js
jslint@0.1.9 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/jslint
└── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
```

Subsequently

```
$ jslint ply.js
zsh: command not found: jslint
```

due to `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` not being in my `$PATH`.

1) Why did `brew` not install global `npm` `bin` path to path? Maybe it did, but something `zsh` does is messing it up. Where might I be able to find that?
2) Should I do this? (Append `:/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to the exported `$PATH` at the bottom of my `~/.zshrc`)

It seems like this isn't the right way to do it because if I install something else later (using Homebrew or something) I'll be needing to append it to my zsh startup script to set the path. I guess in this particular instance it's just a matter of the `npm install -g` not making the right symlinks in a "proper" location (like `/usr/local/bin` maybe).

I think what I will do is manually build out symlinks inside `/usr/local/bin` for any programs that I have trouble with and it should be good enough for my purposes.

**EDIT**: I'm updating this in 2019, because this old question is popular but now outdated both in terms of my personal workflow and also in terms of how to best go about installing node and managing its various dependencies.

My personal workflow is now to use the installer obtained from nodejs.org to install node on systems. I actually trust this more than the homebrew package itself, because it knows best how to manage the files. If you want to change your system node from 8.10 to 10.15, whether on Mac or Windows, simply download the installer from nodejs.org for 10.15 for your OS. Attempting to upgrade node installed via homebrew has always proven to be a more difficult approach in my experience.

Also, the biggest thing to point out is that the use of sudo as shown in my npm install of jslint example above is highly discouraged; I am fairly certain that homebrew packages should never be installed or interacted with in any way using the superuser. It should not be necessary, and will lead to file permission headaches!

Furthermore I recommend ESLint over jslint, and have not used jslint in years.

Comment: Thanks, they're fixed now. I'm not usually that careless but I typed this question up very quickly

Comment: @DaveNewton I usually do that, yeah. This question was a real sloppy one but it's one of my most popular ones.

Comment: isn't it easier to copy text than screenshot? anyway fixed.

Comment: @saleemrashid1 Hey I was meaning to do this. Did you really read it and copy it out? Thanks.

Comment: Yep! You're welcome. I'm working on a game and while I was waiting for NPM to download stuff I did it!

Comment: I recommend `brew unlink node` and `brew install nvm`. It asks you to add some things to your `~/.zshrc` but greatly simplifies keeping multiple versions of node on your system. You can install latest with `nvm install node`.

Comment: @jchook good advice about `nvm`. I still don't use it as much as I should, but it definitely works to reduce head trauma because you have other node versions ready to test at your fingertips.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Extending your `PATH` with:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

isn't a terrible idea. Having said that, you shouldn't have to do it.

Run this:

```
npm config get prefix
```

The default on OS X is `/usr/local`, which means that npm will symlink binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, which should already be on your `PATH` (especially if you're using Homebrew).

So:

1. `npm config set prefix /usr/local` if it's something else, and
2. Don't use `sudo` with npm! According to the [jslint docs](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint), you should just be able to `npm install` it.

If you installed npm as sudo (`sudo brew install`), try reinstalling it with plain ol' `brew install`. Homebrew is supposed to help keep you `sudo`-free.

Comment: Thanks! `npm` refuses to install `jslint` globally, though. `npm install -g jslint` fails. `Error: EACCES, open '/Users/user/.npm/564fcf84-jslint.lock'`

Comment: Wouldn't I need to `chown` `/usr/local` if I am to have any scripts write links into it without requiring `sudo`? How about following [this](http://tnovelli.net/blog/blog.2011-08-27.node-npm-user-install.html) to set nom/node up in `~/.local` or something?

Comment: SWEET! I went and undid the various dirs deposited by user `root` in my `~/` dir (by `sudo rm -r` on `tmp/` and a `.npm/`) and subsequently a `npm install -g jslint` worked beautifully. It's neat that npm itself is a node program and is a bit of a JS command line proof-of-concept for me which I am beginning to appreciate now that I understand it a bit better.

Comment: @StevenLu Yep, `chown`-ing `/usr/local` and everything in it is standard practice on OS X. See the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting) page on the Homebrew wiki.

Comment: Yep it looks like the `chown`ing of `/usr/local` has already occurred on my machine otherwise `npm` et al run without `sudo` would not be able to deposit links into `/usr/local/bin/` etc.

Comment: `NPM_PREFIX=\`npm config get prefix\`` seems a more adaptable way of setting the prefix, then `export PATH="$NPM_PREFIX/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @tadman, thanks for that tip! For me though they would both end up in the same exact place, `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thank you! This has driven me nuts! I think Titanium Studio set that bloody prefix value and it's been ruining everything for me today when I try and install new packages.

Comment: Can someone help me fixing the same issue in windows? I'm on windows7. 

When i do : npm install bower -g, it installs here.

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm

While i try to run bower install underscore, it says bower is not recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: `chown`-ing `/usr/local` is a very hacky quick fix that will likely cause more trouble down the line. It also requires that you re-do it from time to time. It's better for people to setup their paths correctly so they don't have to lean on hacky practices. I agree with @tadman that utilizing  `npm config` and `PATH` is the way to go.

Comment: @wilmoore I would disagree with the assertion that `chown`-ing `/usr/local` is "hacky." It's the standard Homebrew way of doing things, and Homebrew is very popular.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham I'm OK with the fact that we disagree here.

Comment: Sure. There's a good discussion of this very subject at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct

Comment: npm seems to *recommend* using `sudo`: https://github.com/npm/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff

Answer (score 7):

Spent a while on this issue, and the PATH switch wasn't helping. My problem was the Homebrew/node/npm bug found here - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794

If you've already installed node using Homebrew, try ****Note per comments that this might not be safe. It worked for me but could have unintended consequences. It also appears that latest version of Homebrew properly installs npm. So likely I would try `brew update`, `brew doctor`, `brew upgrade node` etc before trying****:

```
npm update -gf
```

Or, if you want to install node with Homebrew and have npm work, use:

```
brew install node --without-npm
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: Casually recommending that people globally force an update is not a good idea.

Comment: Blindly following the advice from someone on the internets is not a good idea.

Comment: The force method on -gf made it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I use brew and the prefix was already set to be:

```
$ npm config get prefix
/Users/[user]/.node
```

I did notice that the bin and lib folder were owned by root, which prevented the usual non sudo install, so I re-owned them to the user

```
$ cd /Users/[user]/.node
$ chown -R [user]:[group] lib
$ chown -R [user]:[group] bin
```

Then I just added the path to my .bash_profile which is located at /Users/[user]

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.node/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix Vue Cli no command error by doing the following:

- In terminal `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` to edit your bash profile.
- Add `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[your username]/.npm-packages/bin`
- Save file and restart terminal
- Now you should be able to use `vue create my-project` and `vue --version` etc.

I did this after I installed the latest Vue Cli from https://cli.vuejs.org/

I generally use yarn, but I installed this globally with npm `npm install -g @vue/cli`. You can use yarn too if you'd like `yarn global add @vue/cli`

Note: you may have to uninstall it first globally if you already have it installed: `npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This basically worked for me. I had to adjust it to export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[your username]/node_modules/.bin

Comment: Even though after I use `export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin` my terminal is finding global packages correctly, I have to manually type it with every further terminal creation. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

brew should not require you to use sudo even when running npm with -g.  This might actually create more problems down the road.

Typically, brew or port let you update you path so it doesn't risk messing up your .zshrc, .bashrc, .cshrc,  or whatever flavor of shell you use.

Comment: Indeed brew does not require and recommends against use of `sudo`. I was using sudo on `npm` (because something I read told me to). I'm curious about where to look up how the path is set. It actually seems like the `zsh` installer runs something that ends up hardcoding the path (at the time of installation of `zsh`) into the `.zshrc` which I'm not liking so much

Comment: Anything installed by `npm` *should* be installed in `/usr/local`. The `/usr` path namespace is reserved for your distro's official packages.
`/usr/local/bin` in your $PATH or not, is a zsh issue.

Comment: the brew scripts do not add anything to your startup script, this is something you need to do.  see http://madebyhoundstooth.com/blog/install-node-with-homebrew-on-os-x/ for an example.

Answer (score 2):

In newer MacOS versions you need to edit the **.zshrc** file not **.bash_profile**:

In your terminal `nano ~/.zshrc`
then add the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[your username]/.npm-packages/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/npm/bin
```

and then do a test by running `express` in the command line. This worked for me.

Comment: pretty sure you mean `~/.npm/bin` or some such. there shouldnt be an `npm` dir added to your home dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked the node packages using sudo command

Then go to the folder where node_modules are installed globally.

On Unix systems they are normally placed in /usr/local/lib/node or /usr/local/lib/node_modules when installed globally. If you set the NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.

Windows XP - %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules
Windows 7 - %AppData%\npm\node_modules

and then run the command

```
ls -l
```

This will give the list of all global node_modules and you can easily see the linked node modules.

Answer (score 0):

sudo brew is no longer an option so if you install with brew at this point you're going to get 2 really obnoxious things:
A: it likes to install into `/usr/local/opts` or according to this, /usr/local/shared. This isn't a big deal at first but i've had issues with node PATH especially when I installed lint.
B: you're kind of stuck with sudo commands until you either uninstall and install it this way or you can get the stack from [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean)

I recommend this method over the stack option because it's ready to go if you have multiple projects. If you go with the premade MEAN stack you'll have to set up virtual hosts in httpd.conf (more of a pain in this stack than XAMPP)plust the usual update your extra/vhosts.conf and /etc/hosts for every additional project, unless you want to repoint and restart your server when you get done updatading things.

Answer (score 0):

Any one got the same issue it's related to a conflict between brew and npm
Please check this solution https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled node from homebrew on M1 Apple Silicon and instead used the Mac Installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/. After doing that I was able to install with npm and npx.

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution is ...

Just put below command :

1. `sudo npm config get prefix`

   if it's not something like  these `/usr/local`, than you need to fix it using below command.
2. `sudo npm config set prefix /usr/local`...

Now it's 100% working fine

Comment: Highly recommend avoiding sudo with npm. See my edit.