# karma command not found when karma already installed

Tags: macos, node.js, terminal, karma-runner

I used node.js to install karma. My first try failed when running the following command on Terminal:

```
npm install -g karma
```

That failed so I decided to use:

```
sudo npm install -g karma
```

After entering my password it seemed to install correctly. 
I am pasting part of the output of the install, maybe it will mean something to someone and it will be relevant to my question. After all the npm http messages this is what I see:

```
> ws@0.4.27 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/karma -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma
karma@0.8.6 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma
├── pause@0.0.1
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── xmlbuilder@0.4.2
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── chokidar@0.6.2
├── growly@1.1.1
├── mime@1.2.9
├── q@0.9.6
├── rimraf@2.1.4 (graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── coffee-script@1.6.3
├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.3.0)
├── optimist@0.3.5 (wordwrap@0.0.2)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── LiveScript@1.0.1 (prelude-ls@1.0.1)
├── log4js@0.6.6 (dequeue@1.0.3, semver@1.1.4, async@0.1.15, readable-stream@1.0.2)
├── lodash@1.1.1
├── http-proxy@0.10.3 (pkginfo@0.2.3, utile@0.1.7)
├── istanbul@0.1.22 (abbrev@1.0.4, which@1.0.5, fileset@0.1.5, nopt@2.0.0, wordwrap@0.0.2, async@0.1.22, mkdirp@0.3.5, esprima@0.9.9, escodegen@0.0.24, handlebars@1.0.12)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)
```

Then when I try to run the following command to create a karma config file with this command:

```
karma init karma.config.js
```

this is the message that gets returned:

```
-bash: karma: command not found
```

I have tried the same command with sudo before it but I get the same result.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on?
Any help is appreciated.

*Update!
I decided to check a file named: builderror.log
located in: /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws

This is what it shows:

```
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/eperez/.node-gyp/0.10.5"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/.node-gyp"
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.5/node-v0.10.5.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.5/node-v0.10.5.tar.gz
```

Comment: it's apparently not in your path, confirm with `which karma`. i've experienced npm installing stuff to a not-in-path-by-default location, I think on Arch. i don't remember where it went though sorry :( ps you can do `cd /; find|grep karma` to get all filenames on system with karma in filename or path

Comment: I ran the command and this is what I got. Not sure what it means though:  `usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]`

Comment: OK sorry your `find` program behaves differently than mine. Anyway you will need to find where npm installed stuff and make sure that folder is added to your path for your terminal sessions. FWIW on my Linux Mint install, `npm -g` puts stuff in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I have the same issue. None of the suggestions/answers helped.

Comment: The command line interface is in a separate package.

To install this use:

`npm install -g karma-cli`

Answer (score 255, accepted):

[@mayankcpdixit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895600/mayankcpdixit) gave the answer up there in a response to the OP's original question, but I'll put it here again in case anyone misses it.

You do not need to uninstall everything, and if I had to manually add a new path link for every npm package I try to install I'd probably shoot myself.

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Boom.  Now you have karma command lines installed.  Just like Grunt.

---

Edit:  Please don't forget to upvote [@mayankcpdixit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895600/mayankcpdixit) as well, he commented directly on the original post, but didn't actually "answer" the question.

Comment: Remember that `-g` requires sudo privileges so it should be `sudo npm install -g karma-cli` ;)

Answer (score 37):

In your `~/.bash_profile` (or similar) amend your `PATH` to include npm-installed binaries:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin"
```

I had this very same issue, and found this solution to be less time-consuming and impactful than completely re-installing node.

**EDIT** this has also worked for others in `bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/bin"
```

Comment: I had to use:

```export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/bin"```


in ```~/.bash_profile```.

Comment: Can't decide whether to make sure Karma is in my path or completely reinstall Node... +1

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. This is with a global installation or karma, correct?

Comment: @grant sorry you couldn't get it to work (and for this late response). Yes, it was with a global installation of karma.

Comment: @MartinCortez no problem. I found out that my problem had to do with the node prefix which wasn't set to /usr/local as it should have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix

Comment: if you are using oh my zsh make the edits in ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 15):

It is recommended to install karma with its Command-Line-Interface ([karma-cli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-cli)) which will take care of fetching the appropriate karma. You can also install a different local version specific to each project you're working on and karma-cli will pick the appropriate one.

From the karma [installation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html) page:

Typing ***./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start*** sucks so you might find it useful to install karma-cli globally:

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Now, check that karma was installed by typing:

```
karma start
```

You can also check that karma was installed by going to this directory:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to completely uninstall node.js

Just

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/
```

Then
**install node.js**

Then
**reinstall karma**

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/karma/bin` after installing karma with `sudo npm install karma`.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to test.sh:

Find: `$BASE_DIR/../node_modules/karma/bin/karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*`

Replace with: `/usr/local/bin/karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*`

Or: `karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma.conf.js $*`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. It looks like karma for command line is a separate package which can be installed by

`npm install -g karma-cli`

Comment: For anyone's info: I also had to add karma-cli to my package.json so it would run on Circle CI.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading from Karma 0.10 to 0.12 the link to the karma executable is removed.

You can get it back with

```
cd node_modules/.bin
ln -s ../karma/bin/karma karma
```

Answer (score -21):

Try re-installing node.js. There are lots of ways to install it, but I recommend downloading from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/download/)

If that doesn't work, you may try to re-install karma.

Comment: I had originally installed node through homebrew. I unlinked node then downloaded node.js from the website. Installed the pkg file and everything seems to be working fine now. Thank you!