# npm command not found after updating to Mac OSX 10.9.4

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I can't do npm command on terminal after updating my OS to Mavericks.

when I try this: `node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js -v` it is working and showing the version 1.4.3

I don't know what's happening here, can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try relinking the bin:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/bin/npm
```

You might need to run as root.

Comment: Great! How about cordova?

Comment: I've never used it, so i don't know. You could try the same thing.

Comment: Okay, i just thought you know where cordova is saved. Thanks