# Cordova Installed but command not found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I have installed Cordova correctly (I think!), but i cannot run the command via Terminal "cordova", not even with sudo.

What can be the issue here?

```
123hej:~ jesper$ sudo npm install -g cordova
 /Users/jesper/.node/bin/cordova ->        /Users/jesper/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
 cordova@4.3.0 /Users/jesper/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova
 ├── underscore@1.7.0
 ├── q@1.0.1
 ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
 └── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, dep-graph@1.1.0, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, npmconf@0.1.16, elementtree@0.1.5, glob@4.0.6, init-package-json@1.3.0, d8@0.4.4, request@2.47.0, plist@1.1.0, npm@1.3.4, tar@1.0.2, cordova-js@3.8.0)
 123hej:~ jesper$ cordova
 -bash: cordova: command not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [-bash: cordova: command not found; or -bash: phonegap: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975330/bash-cordova-command-not-found-or-bash-phonegap-command-not-found)

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, none of the solution worked. Already seen that.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I am new to mobile technologies. I need to install cordova in my laptop which is having Windows-10 64 bit. Can you please let me know how you have installed cordova with detailed steps. I have already asked a question in the same forum. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624037/what-is-the-procedure-to-install-cordova-in-windows