# Cordova command not found - can not be used globally

Tags: macos, cordova, command-line-interface

so I have installed cordova using the following command to use it globally

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

and I get the following message

```
/Users/safwany/.node/bin/cordova -> /Users/safwany/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@5.1.1 /Users/safwany/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova
```

I keep typing `cordova` in the terminal but I am getting command not found. The only I can get it working is by typing the following:

```
/Users/safwany/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
```

Any idea how can I change that so I can use it globally by just typing `cordova` ?!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with the CHMOD rights of your folders. Try to own the folders like this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
sudo chmod -R 0775 /usr/local
```

after that, clear the npm cache with

```
sudo npm cache clear
```

finished? Go on by installing cordova again ->

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

type `cordova` into your terminal and everything should work like a charme.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113963/3671726

Comment: type `echo $PATH` into your terminal and post the output here please.

Comment: /Users/safwany/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/safwany/.rvm/bin