# /bin/sh: cordova: command not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to run the below:

> ionic platform add ios

However, I got:

> /bin/sh: cordova: command not found
>   Caught exception:
>    undefined
>
> Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.7
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

I already installed `cordova` but for some reason it was not detected by Ionic

What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975330/bash-cordova-command-not-found-or-bash-phonegap-command-not-found

Comment: You can see here to fix issue: [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975330/bash-cordova-command-not-found-or-bash-phonegap-command-not-found/55759746#55759746)

Answer (score 0):

After successfull installetion of cordova you will get the output like this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.2.0/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.2.0/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova

+ cordova@10.0.0

updated 1 package in 127.643s
```

Now copy the path and make a siblink into your local installetion directory.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.2.0/bin/cordova /usr/local/bin
```

Now cordova will be available for use by cordova command.