# Command error running installed npm modules

Tags: macos, node.js, command, npm

Hi guys could you help me? i've installed the latest version of node.js and installed cordova and ionic framework the problem starts is when i'm trying to run the ionic command, the console throw me the following message:

MacBook-Pro-de-Diego:~ diegochavez$ ionic start myApp
-bash: ionic: command not found

So then i looked for the root of my npm modules
MacBook-Pro-de-Diego:~ diegochavez$ npm root
/Users/diegochavez/node_modules

if you guys know something to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First check if `ionic` is installed at path like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic`. If it is there, you need to check the npm default global path.

Run command `npm config get prefix` to check the default path, it should be `/usr/local`. If it is not `/usr/local`, run command `npm config set prefix /usr/local` to set it. And then install again. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840304/111277)

Answer (score 0):

I having issue while running - sudo npm install -g gulp ionic    with below version of node installed

node -v v0.10.15
npm -v 1.3.5

Error went way after I update node to latest version v0.10.26

The error you are getting is because ionic was not installed successfully. Trying updating node and run command as mentioned **sudo npm install -g gulp ionic**

Answer (score 0):

Check where your npm folder is located. If your npm folder is located in $Home..then type this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to run `sudo npm install -g ionic` from the command line.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks, but i've installed ionic, but my problem starts when i'm trying to run the command, command can't be found.