# Ember-CLI Installation not recognized

Tags: node.js, linux, ember.js, ember-cli

I have followed the following tutorial and have successfully installed everything but ember-cli.
http://www.ember-cli.com/#getting-started

- node --help (shows output help messages)
- npm --help  (shows output help messages )
- npm install -g bower
- npm install -g phantomjs

All the above work with no problems but when I try to `ember new my-new-app`
I got the following

```
$ ember new my-new-app
-bash: ember: command not found
```

When I do `$ npm install -g ember-cli`
I get the following

```
$ npm install -g ember-cli
/Users/MGK/.node/bin/ember -> /Users/MGK/.node/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
ember-cli@0.1.4 /Users/MGK/.node/lib/node_modules/ember-cli
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── js-string-escape@1.0.0
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── temp@0.8.1 (rimraf@2.2.8)
├── symlink-or-copy@1.0.1 (copy-dereference@1.0.0)
├── http-proxy@1.7.3 (requires-port@0.0.0, eventemitter3@0.1.6)
├── broccoli-writer@0.1.1 (rsvp@3.0.14, quick-temp@0.1.2)
├── yam@0.0.17 (findup@0.1.5, fs-extra@0.8.1, lodash@2.4.1)
└── broccoli-caching-writer@0.5.1 (promise-map-series@0.2.0, rimraf@2.2.8, quick-         temp@0.1.2, rsvp@3.0.14, core-object@0.0.2, broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers@0.2.5)
```

Any ideas?

**Update**, here is my `echo $PATH`

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/MGK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you try `ember new my-new-app` again after running `npm install -g ember-cli`?

Comment: Yup, still getting `-bash: $: command not found`

Comment: Your paths are probably screwed up. Is `bower` found? Check to make sure the directory containing globally-installed node modules executables is on your path.

Comment: @torazaburo That's what I was thinking. @Mills If you have trouble evaluating your path on your own, you could always update your question with the contents of `echo $PATH`

Comment: @torazaburo yes bower is found, @wisew let me update my question with my `echo $PATH` output, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that npm's path isn't in your `$PATH` variable, so your shell has no idea where to look for any of your npm modules. There are a few ways to remedy this:

1. Run `npm config get prefix`. Open your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` config file and add the following line:

   `export PATH="~/.node/bin:$PATH"`

   This will add your npm executables to your path. (`~/.node/bin` was taken from the console output when you installed ember-cli)

   Then run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` depending on which file you edited. This will load the changes you've made to your `$PATH`. Or:
2. Run `npm config set prefix /usr/local` (`/usr/local` since you're on a Mac and it's already in your $PATH).

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix) for a more general instance of the same npm installation issue.)

Comment: I have /usr/local as the prefix and added that to my path.. still no luck

Answer (score 1):

For windows users;
Add your nmp path to the `PATH` environment variable.
Start-> Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables

Under the System Variables section, click Path and then edit.
Add C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm to the list. 
After a restart it worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

is there literally that giant gap (tab or spaces) in the in your path when you run $PATH?

if so, your path may be corrupt because of that whitespace.  based on the PATH your provided, try doing this to reset your PATH. paste this line into your terminal window:

```
PATH=/Users/MGK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/MGK/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: I updated my $PATH above, the whitespace is not there anymore. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

As said by @wisew, the issue is that npm path not being set in the path variable!

I faced the same issue in my win7 machine, I fixed the issue by adding `"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm"` to the path variable as below.

1. open command prompt (`cmd`) and run
   `setx "%path%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm"`
2. Reopen the `cmd` to confirm the changes
3. run command `ember`

You should be seeing that ember command is detected now and is working :)

Thank you!