# How to solve: yaml2json command not found?

Tags: json, parsing, npm, yaml

I wanted to install a command line tool to convert yaml files into json files. Actually My real intention is to validate yaml files all at once in a directory.

I did some research and followed the instructions listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml2json) and [here](https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/yaml2json/1.0.2). However, command line always tells me that `-bash: yaml2json: command not found`. I'm wondering if it's because the files weren't in my path? my `$PATH` looks like this:

```
/Users/luca/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:~/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

What should I do to get this work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you use the `-g` option with `npm install`? It looks like your `$PATH` is correct. Does `/usr/local/bin/yaml2json` exist (it should be a symlink)? I suggest taking a look at this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix/14840304#14840304

Comment: Thank you! I used `-g` to install yaml2json, but the command line always throws me errors looking like this `npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/venga-penny/.npm/yaml2json/1.0.2/package.tgz`
`npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0`
`npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yaml2json"`
... So I'm not sure what is going wrong...

Answer (score 3):

- if you are using `Ubuntu` use the below command to install the required package:

  - `sudo apt install libghc-yaml-dev`
- if you are using RHEL/CentOS use the below command to get the name of the package:

  - `yum provides *bin/yaml2json`
  - then install the package using `sudo yum install <package-name>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `sudo npm install-g yaml2json` can solve the problem...But this yaml2json module can only work with one file at a time instead of files in a directory...

Plus when I run `yaml2json ./_index.yaml`, it returns `"project_path"`
Not sure what it means and can't find the converted .json file either...