# Why are modules missing from `npm list -g --depth=0`?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have `gulp` and `bower` installed globally.

For some reason, neither of them appear in `npm list`.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? What am I missing?

```
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/lib
├── colorguard@1.0.1
├── contributors@0.5.0
├── git-contributors@0.2.3
├── js-beautify@1.5.10
├── jslint@0.9.6
└── npm@2.14.12

nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ npm list -g | grep bower
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ bower -v
1.7.2
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ which bower
/usr/local/bin/bower
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ ll `which bower`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan  6 12:05 /usr/local/bin/bower -> ../lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower*
nathanbrauer@macthan:~$ ll /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 nobody nathanbrauer 4096 Jan  6 16:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root         4096 Jan  6 11:41 ../
drwxr-xr-x 6 nobody nathanbrauer 4096 Jan  6 12:05 bower/
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nathanbrauer 4096 Jan  6 16:12 es6-promise/
drwxr-xr-x 6 nobody nathanbrauer 4096 Jan  6 11:41 gulp/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like things like gulp and Bower are installed in `/usr/lib` while the rest of your files are in `/usr/local/lib`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840304/2532070) suggests that npm usually installs into `/usr/local/lib` via symlink if you have your `$PATH` setup correctly (and you're not installing via `sudo`), so presumably you changed that variable sometime in the past.

If `npm root` doesn't return `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` then resetting your `prefix` variable with `npm config set prefix /usr/local` should do the trick.

I'd just delete the `node_modules` you have in `/usr/lib` and reinstall once your `prefix` is set properly.