# what's the destination does 'npm install -g xxx' install to?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, sinopia

For instance, **npm install -g sinopia**

On windows7, I will install the sinopia command and related modules inside **C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm.**

On Redhat5, my node and npm command are in /usr/local/clo/ven/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin. When I run 'npm install -g sinopia',  by default, sinopia was got installed in the current directory as npm and node like below.
[image]

But currently I got a linux machine that has got sinopia installed by other person. I can not find the start script of sinopia inside node/bin, and I can find sinopia related stuff like below.
[image].
Where can I find the start script of sinopia? Whether the installation location of the 'npm install -g xxx' can be configured?

Comment: have a look at this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm installs packages globally to its set global "root". To find what the global root is in a given environment, run `npm root -g`.

It will typically be inside the "prefix" directory, which you can find with `npm prefix -g`.

Note you can also change the prefix directory with `npm config -g set prefix </new/prefix/path>`.

---

> To answer your more specific question

In order to find the `sinopia` executable, you can run `which sinopia` on linux (you might need to install `which` on RedHat, it should be available in your package sources). It will give you the pathname of the file that would be executed for the `sinopia` command.

But that could be a symlink to another location; to resolve the pathname you can use `readlink -f $(which sinopia)` on bash. The `-f` option tells `readlink` to follow links recursively. `$(which sinopia)` will be substituted by the output of the `which sinopia` command.

Answer (score 0):

Quick edit as I see this has already been answered above.

To find the install location of packages installed globally through npm, run the following:

> npm config get prefix

to update this you can use the following command:

> npm config set prefix *path*

Source: [npm global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix)

Comment: Actually, you're missing the `-g` or `--global` flag. Without it, he'd get the local prefix (which might or might not be the same as the global one, depending on where it's executed).

Comment: I ran './npm config get prefix', got /usr/local/bfadmin/node, but sinopia can not be found inside it, this directory is node binary itself.

Comment: Pretty sure I am right, see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix.  Thing I was missing was a path after the set statement.  Updating it now.  liam, npm should be in your path.  you shouldn't be running it from your local directory.