# "Permission Denied" when trying to install ESlint on OSX globally

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, eslint

This is what I'm trying to do on my mac: `npm install eslint -g`

And I get a `EACCES: permission denied` with the following details:

```
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/HOME/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/eslint/LICENSE' }
```

How can I install ESlint globally without using `sudo`? Or should I use `sudo`?

Comment: The best option is use *nvm* (Node Version Manager), with it you can install several versions of nodejs in the same machine, and it save your global modules in your user folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to `~/.npmrc`:

```
prefix = ${HOME}/.npm-packages
```

https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Also do search before you ask:
[npm global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix)
[NPM modules won't install globally without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352976/npm-modules-wont-install-globally-without-sudo?rq=1)

Comment: I am terribly new to `npm` and even OSX terminal and commands! Anyways, I seem to have installed it, but get `command not found` when running `eslint .`

Comment: You also have to add `${HOME}/.npm-packages/.bin` to your `PATH` so that your shell knows where to look up the globally installed scripts.