# ESlint Error Install from Command Line

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, eslint

I get the following error installing eslint:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "eslint"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.8
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Leviathan/lj/npm-debug.log
```

I have not been able to figure out how to install eslint and also get this line:

eslint --init to run to create the .eslintrc file

Comment: For what it's worth, it's almost never a good idea to install ESLint globally - running scripts directly from `package.json` includes `node_modules/.bin` in your `PATH` automatically. Also, avoid running `sudo` when you can - change or loosen permissions if needed. `/usr/local/` should be pretty liberal in who can read/write things within it, in particular.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install globally while your user doesn't have access to the global  node_modules folder. You can try installing it as root or chown  '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'.

Install as root -

```
    sudo npm install -g eslint
```

Chown -

```
    chown user:group /usr/local/lib/node_modules
    npm install -g eslint
```

You can also change permissions to /usr/local/lib/node_modules to allow your user access using chmod.

Edit:
Try the solution in the answer here
["Permission Denied" when trying to install ESlint on OSX globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156292/permission-denied-when-trying-to-install-eslint-on-osx-globally)

Add this to ~/.npmrc:

prefix = ${HOME}/.npm-packages
https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md
You also have to add ${HOME}/.npm-packages/.bin to your PATH so that your shell knows where to look up the globally installed scripts.

Comment: I still get the same errors for the first command, and cant run eslint --init afterwards,

for the chown... line when i enter it in it in the terminal i get:

chown: user: illegal user name

if i put my username instead of chown i still get the same error with:

-bash: username: command not found

Comment: I am new to using the terminal, so the suggestions in your link and reply are sort of confusing, so what should i enter line by line in the terminal, as I keep getting -bash permission denied, command not found, or no such file or directory when trying those suggestions

Comment: Do you know how to use a terminal editor like vi or nano? If not what editor do you use?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by installing as root as you said. Strangely, i tried this before from a blog post online, but now it works for some reason? maybe the server was down

Answer (score 31):

If you're getting **`eslint: command not found`** try:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

Comment: Great answer for if you don't want to install it globally!

Answer (score 6):

Try

`npm install eslint --save-dev` and then `eslint --init`.

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: I get a few warnings and I also get this:

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@~0.4.0

and when i try to run eslint --init it says:

-bash: eslint: command not found

Comment: you have to run it from your project folder /node_modules/.bin/eslint --init. This is safe when compared to other methods.

Answer (score 1):

May be updating the dependencies to their latest versions (including major version changes) in the package.json file. would save you time.

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
```

or you may have to install eslint globally.

```
npm i eslint -g
```

and after removing node modules of your current project

```
eslint --init
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install eslint inside your directory and run this command

```
npm init @eslint/config
```

Answer (score 0):

For: `Zsh: command not found: eslint`

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save --dev
```

then run:

```
npm install -g eslint
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Run a general update to upgrade all outdated packages
run `npm outdated` to see updated packages then
run `npm update`
also
`npm-check-updates` and `npm install` to finish up and your bug might be fixed

Answer (score -1):

`eslint --init to run to create the .eslintrc file` is says create .eslintrc, you probably forgot to include `.` before eslintrc