# Having trouble installing ember

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, homebrew

```
npm install -g ember-cli
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.1/libexec/npm/bin/ember -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.1/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.1/libexec/npm/lib
└── ember-cli@2.9.1
```

The above is the command is what I've used to install ember. But when I type `ember -v` it shows `-bash: ember: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats not really `ember` related. It's an `npm` problem. Whats your `npm` version, and how have you installed `npm`? If you've installed it with homebrew (I'm not sure if you get a current npm & node version there) have you followed all instructions to modify your `PATH`?

Comment: i have used homebrew to install and current version of npm is 3.10.3

Comment: Maybe checkout (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix].

Comment: Thanks a lot:) The link helped!