# How to cd into global node_modules on mac

Tags: macos, npm, node-modules

I want to access example file in protractor I am trying to find my way to get into usr/local/lib

How do I cd into this "special" folder on mac

Comment: Hi take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix regards.

Comment: @headmax it gives me the answer to get the prefix. How do I actually cd into the directory and run an ls- l

Comment: if you do a echo $PATH can you known where nodejs is installed ? or can you use the linux command whereis nodejs may be that match no sure :( or a find the node_modules and compare where node_modules is the big one at size KB.

Comment: I did echo $PATH, and node modules wasn't in the list

Comment: Try find / -name "node_modules", in the result look at the modules got the big size is the one your looking for.

Comment: I can find /usr/local/lib/node_modules  but HOW do i cd into that directory. that's my only issue getting inside that folder from terminal. What is the ABSOLUTE path to that particular folder

Comment: without home/user you need to be admin so try to login on admin you can do if is running like linux and you got sudo on your machine a simple : sudo -i and you will jump as admin and you can do a cd to ... but you can to try a sudo cd /to/the/directory/private you go a simple explain here http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac

Comment: What is the ABSOLUTE path to that particular folder? it's an Absolute path /usr/local/lib/node_modules if i want a RELATEIVE path to usr/lib i can type to the console : export USER_LIB /usr/lib/ ,after this you got a RELATIVE path and you can access with USER_LIB/node_modules but is another question, regards.