# Fixing Global Node Installs

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, command-line-interface, prefix

I've spent several hours trying solutions, but realized I didn't fully understand the problem. Now that I think I understand the problem, I can't find a proper solution. It is possible I'm simply misunderstanding solutions I've found, so if this is a repetitive post I apologize.

My issue is my Node global install. I ran `node config ls -l` and saw something perplexing.

My user-agent prefix is **/Users/me/.npm** and my builtin prefix is **/usr/local**, but has been overridden (as expected).

All of my previous global installs are under /usr/local, also as expected. My new global installs are going under /Users/me/.npm/lib/node_modules, which I also expected since I set a prefix manually from another solution.

My global config is **/Users/me/.npm/etc**, which DOES NOT EXIST. The etc directory doesn't exist and the global config doesn't seem to exist. There is not a global config under /usr/local/etc, but /usr/local/etc does exist.

I have tried changing PATH under .bashrc and .bash_profile. When I check my files, I no longer even have a PATH=$PATH:directory in .bash_profile, and .bashrc is completely empty.

My global packages which are being executed are the ones installed under usr/local/lib/node_modules. The ones being installed are now going to /Users/me/.npm/lib/node_modules.

I want to set all of my globals back to **/usr/local**, so my packages install and execute from **/usr/local/lib/node_modules**.

Answer (score 0):

It was a misunderstanding on my part, and the answer posted here resolved my issue.
( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840304/11046625 )