# Bower: "command not found" after installation

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, homebrew, bower

I seem to be getting the following when I execute `npm install bower -g`

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/bower -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@0.8.6 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/bower
```

Unfortunately executing any of the bower commands returns `-bash: bower: command not found`

`which npm` returns `/usr/local/bin/npm` and running `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`.

Comment: Related posts - [bower is not recognised as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27360710/465053) & [bower command not found windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21732447/465053)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I assume you installed Node.js through Homebrew, which annoyingly puts installed npm binaries in a place that is usually not in a users path. All you have to do is to add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` to your $PATH. You do that by adding `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH` to your .bashrc/.bash_profile/.zshrc file.

Although I would rather uninstall the Homebrew installed Node.js and install it with the installer from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) which doesn't have this problem.

*This problem is not Bower specific and will be noticeable with any globally installed Node.js binary, eg. grunt, uglify, jshint, etc.*

Comment: LOL My Hero! thanks. Yeah, I installed it through homebrew. Everything is a fresh install on a new machine and homebrew seemed to be the easiest to get going with packages and dependencies. I'm also using Paul's dotfiles with the `.extra` file in my `~` to control paths. In my `.extra` file is now the line above with the `export PATH` line you outlined.

    `# PATH additions`
    `PATH=$PATH:~/.rvm/bin # ruby`
    `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH # local path`
    `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH # Boom! Works now \m/`

Comment: I just wanted to add that I ended up uninstalling Node.js from the Homebrew installation and installed Node.js from the installer via the Node.js Website. This allowed me not having to add the PATH stuff mentioned previously resulting in a much cleaner install.

Comment: And I just wanted to add that on Windows 7, I had to add C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm to my path.

Comment: I installed Node through the `.pkg` installer from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and it doesn't put npm binaries in my path either. As far as I can tell it puts them in `~/.npm-packages/bin/`, but never mentions you need to add this to your path.

Answer (score 9):

For users that are encountering issues with the installation in mac as shown in the official page, it seems that El Capitan is giving permission issues to install the package in that way:

`npm install bower -g`

The **solution** I've found to avoid the permission errors is using `sudo` (superuser do) to provide access for node to download the package like this:

`sudo npm install bower -g`

Hopefully this may help users having the same problem. :)

Answer (score 6):

I know this question has been answered and accepted long time ago. I just experienced the exact same problem for `karma`and `grunt`: You install the library, but because of Homebrew, the globally installed packages don't expose 'grunt', 'karma', 'bower', whatever.

Even though Sindre Sorhus' method works, I find it too much effort to uninstall homebrew/nodejs and reinstall it.

Instead I used

```
npm install -g grunt-bower-cli
```

and same for the others:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Grunt's documentation explains why you need this step:

> This will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be
>   run from any directory.
>
> Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner!
>   The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has
>   been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of
>   Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

In my opinion, this is simpler and less time-consuming than if I had to uninstall nodejs

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Sticking with Homebrew it's imperative to not have to keep track of all sort of installers over time...

Answer (score 6):

If you have a 'non standard' installation, you need to find the node bin location location with:

```
npm config list
```

Then add the node bin location to your `~/.bash_profile`

`export PATH=<yourNodeBinLocation>:$PATH`

Remember to open a new terminal to test, or `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is by far the best answer as it does not depend on a specific platform

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In Mac OS X add next row into your ~/.bash_profile

`export PATH="$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/bower/bin:$PATH"`

And restart terminal or type:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is the best example and should be used for anyone that installed node with homebrew

Answer (score 1):

If you used something other than Homebrew (yes, some of us actually did it weird) —like MacPorts, your `$PATH` could be funky. Binaries may be located in other areas:
 `/opt/local/bin/grunt` and possibly `/opt/local/bin/npm`

Additionally if you use MacPorts to install npm then subsequently install bower, the binary will not be located where you'd expect. It actually ends up in your home directory under `.npm/lib/node_modules/bower/bin`

Your `$PATH` should be adjusted in ~/.profile (Mac OS X) to add:    `$HOME/.npm/lib/node_modules/bower/bin`

Source your Bash profile or open a new terminal window and it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

i add this

```
export PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

at the end (and new line) of my .bash_profile file( located in user folder). Save it. close and reopen terminal

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2016, the .pkg installer from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) arranges for installed packages to be under `$HOME/.npm-packages/lib/node-modules`, with symlinks in `~/.npm-packages/bin`:

```
$ bower install
-bash: bower: command not found
$ which bower
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-packages/bin
$ which bower
/Users/dmoles/.npm-packages/bin/bower
```

Comment: awesome! This solution worked for me. I am using a macOSX

Answer (score 1):

If all of the above doesn't work, or you don't seem to understand the answers provided to the question.

I suggest you run the installation commands on your system command prompt and not git-bash, especially if your are on windows 8 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the Homebrew/node/npm bug found here - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794

If you've already installed node using Homebrew, try:

```
npm update -gf
```

Or, if you want to install node with Homebrew and have npm work, use:

```
brew install node --without-npm
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In centos 6.8

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

add three row below

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

and then

```
exec /bin/zsh
```

or

```
exec /usr/bin/zsh
```

just work