# npm: issue with bower command not found

Tags: terminal, alias, npm, bower

I installed bower using node package manager but I always get 'bower command not found'. 
But if I type `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/bower` it works fine.

I read I had to add `export PATH=~/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH` to ~/.profile but I'm not sure if I added it correctly

[image]

If someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["command not found" after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation)

Comment: aha ... no idea why I didn't find that one when I searched for the problem. Oh well ... got it fixed in the end and that's what matters to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the wrong file. it was .bash_profile instead of .profile

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Forgot about it. i couldn't accept it yet when I posted the answer.