# grunt: command not found when running from terminal

Tags: gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt. I'm trying to configure Grunt on my Mac OSX Lion.

I followed the instructions [here](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and then created a project folder that contains the files below. When I try to run by typing "grunt" into terminal I get `command not found`. I've also modified my paths `sudo nano /etc/paths` in the hope that adding the path would make the task runner work but it's still not working. Can someone assist with this please?

```
---paths

/usr/bin 
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/grunt


--- files
node modules
Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

Comment: run this command from the terminal and add the output to your question: which grunt

Comment: Hi Paul, I typed the command and received no output at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["command not found" after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667381/node-package-grunt-installed-but-not-available - great answer there.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm guessing you used Brew to install Node, so the guide here might be helpful http://madebyhoundstooth.com/blog/install-node-with-homebrew-on-os-x/.

You need to ensure that the npm/bin is in your path as it describes `export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"`. This is the location that npm will install the bin stubs for the installed packages.

---

The nano version will also work as described here http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/ but a restart of Terminal may be required to have the new path picked up.

Comment: can i add this using sudo nano /etc/paths ?

Comment: Looks like it here http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/ but use `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` rather than the `/usr/local/bin/grunt` you have in the question

Comment: I added the path using sudo nano /etc/paths but I still have no grunt commands
    /usr/local/share/npm/bin

Comment: how do I get to that folder in terminal?

Comment: I managed to unhide the folder using finder. My npm folder sits under /Users/myusername.

Comment: I ran that command you recommended and I received the following output: grunt  grunt-init

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31018/discussion-between-nschonni-and-user686483)

Comment: now changed: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin, can be seen after npm install.

Comment: still doesn't help me - maybe the path is different?

Answer (score 509):

My fix for this on Mountain Lion was: -

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Saw it on http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: also on Lion (10.7.4)

Comment: Also on linux, (Ubuntu / Elementary OS)

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. grunt is the library, grunt-cli is the command-line tool.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Should work just fine (and is probably better) without the `sudo`.

Comment: @MatthewShanley `sudo` is needed unless appropriate folder permissions were set when installing `npm` itself.

Comment: If you need `sudo`, permissions are wrong and you will get yourself in deeper trouble every install. Always make sure `npm` can run without `sudo`.

Comment: Agree with @LaurensKling. Fix your npm permission problem by following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Comment: Awesome. Worked on Mac OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Works with El Capitain!

Comment: Works on Sierra !

Comment: Works on macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Answer (score 13):

For windows

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

`npm install load-grunt-tasks`

Then run

`grunt`

Comment: didn't help me at all

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and only had to run 'npm install -g grunt-cli'

Answer (score 6):

I have been hunting around trying to solve this one for a while and none of the suggested updates to bash seemed to be working.  What I discovered was that some point my npm root was modified such that it was pointing to a `Users/USER_NAME/.node/node_modules` while the actual installation of npm was living at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.  You can check this by running `npm root` and `npm root -g` (for the global installation).  To correct the path you can call `npm config set prefix /usr/local`.

Comment: I am not able to synch up the two paths using the solution you provided

Answer (score 6):

Also on OS X (El Capitan), been having this same issue all morning.

I was running the command "npm install -g grunt-cli" command from within a directory where my project was.

I tried again from my home directory (i.e. 'cd ~') and it installed as before, except now I can run the grunt command and it is recognised.

Answer (score 5):

the key point is finding the right path where your grunt was installed. 
I installed grunt through npm, but my grunt path was `/Users/${whoyouare}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt`. So after I added `/Users/${whoyouare}/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin` to `~/.bash_profile`,and `source ~/.bash_profile`, It worked.

So the steps are as followings:

`1. find the path where your grunt was installed(when you installed grunt, it told you. if you don't remember, you can install it one more time)`

`2. vi ~/.bash_profile`

`3. export PATH=$PATH:/your/path/where/grunt/was/installed`

`4. source ~/.bash_profile`

You can refer 
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grunt-command-not-found/

Comment: Great answer, worked for me (Win7 x64). This is what I placed in my .bash_profile: `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`

Comment: Also check `~/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt` (OS X High Sierra)