# Grunt server: command not found in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-requirejs

In my project directory, I installed Grunt by using the following command:

```
npm install grunt
```

...after that I did Grunt server in my project directory but it gives me command not found error.

```
Raj$ grunt server
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

And:

```
npm install grunt
npm WARN package.json BID-2.0@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json BID-2.0@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json BID-2.0@0.0.0 No README data
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: so you have the json file package.json?
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#package.json

Comment: @denis thanks for your reply yes I have package.json filr

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I'm assuming that you have node, npm installed? (check with node -v and npm -v)... 
*also - is node, npm installed globally*
(with sudo or with the -g)

Comment: Also - What are your versions for node and NPM

Comment: You need grunt-cli, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18877352/1366361

Comment: possible duplicate of [grunt: command not found when running from terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868924/grunt-command-not-found-when-running-from-terminal)

Answer (score 6):

You need to install **Grunt**'s command line interface (CLI) globally as well.

From their site:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

You may need to use `sudo` command (for OSX, *nix, BSD etc) or run your command shell as Administrator (for Windows) to do this.

This will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be run from any directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install grunt after installing node / npm with:  `npm install -g grunt`.  Then it will be available at the cmd.