# Install ionic framework.

Tags: ionic-framework

I have installed the module with node version v0.10.22

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

But know when I am trying to start an new application I am getting a

```
-bash command not found
which ionic
```

gives me nothing, do I have to add the path to on the $PATH variable ?

Comment: What about using cordova to install ionic? 

      npm install -g cordova ionic

Answer (score 1):

How did you installed npm? If you used homebrew then npm won't put npm files accessible by users.

Add `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH` to your `.bashrc/.bash_profile/.zshrc` file and it should work fine.

Also refer this: [Bower: "command not found" after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation)