# zsh: command not found: modernizr

Tags: npm, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I installed modernizr: `npm install -g modernizr`
Everything went well without errors: `/Users/myusername/npm/bin/modernizr -> /Users/myusername/npm/lib/node_modules/modernizr/bin/modernizr
/Users/myusername/npm/lib`

After install running: `modernizr` I get:

> zsh: command not found: modernizr

In my .zshrc file I have:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

After googling around find this post: [Bower: "command not found" after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846076/command-not-found-after-installation/15850125#15850125) and added this line to my .zshrc file: `export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH`

When I type `which npm` I get `/usr/local/bin/npm`

But I'm still getting command not found.
I checked files with Mac Finder and found modernizer in myusername/npm/node_modules/modernizer - this should be right? How to fix zsh command not found?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change PATH export to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$HOME/npm/bin
```

You can also remove the double quotes.

Comment: I did change export PATH but still getting `command not found`

Comment: Can you paste the output from 'ls -l $HOME/npm/node_modules/modernizer'? Maybe it needs to have executable settings.

Comment: It says `ls: /Users/myusername/npm/node_modules/modernizer: No such file or directory`. Oh, actually my right bath is `/Users/myusername/npm/lib/node_modules/modernizer`

Comment: Aah, try 'ls -l $HOME/npm/bin'. Can you find the file modernizr? I changed the path setting above. Does your path include $HOME/npm/bin?

Answer (score 0):

For **WSL2 + NVM user**:

1. Add following to the end of ~/.zshrc

> ***ignore last line if bash_completion not installed

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" #npm package
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" #loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" #loads nvm bash_completion
```

2. Restart terminal