# how to install bower globally?

Tags: windows, bower, bower-install

Tried to install bower in a directory but wont let me. Followed this guideline: [bower command not found windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732447/bower-command-not-found-windows).

So in the command line I did:

```
npm config get prefix
```

Then I did in that directory:
npm install bower.

Any ideas how to get bower working globally?

Comment: Try running `npm install -g bower`.

Answer (score 0):

To install bower globally you run:
`npm install bower -g`. You might need to run in administrator mode to install globally