# Bower install from Windows 10 bash

Tags: windows, bash, bower

I have checked the question "[bower command not found windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732447/bower-command-not-found-windows)" and many more, but still can't find an answer for bash inside windows 10.

I am not very familiar with windows and bash so I always have troubles doing anything dev-oriented on windows.

So I could install npm from windows command prompt then run `npm install bower` from command prompt. then when I type `bower` in windows command prompt no problem it will find it. But from bash, `bower` returns `No such file or directory`. Still if I do npm from bash it will work.

Then I tried from bash:

```
sudo su
npm install -gf bower
```

and got:

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.8.0.tgz
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.8.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
```

After that `bower` is still unknown.

I think it is a path problem...
This `echo $PATH`
will return

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a while I found a way, so I found good to share is someone has same problem.

1. I inspected my `$PATH` where it was missing the bower path, I
   edited it with:
   `PATH=$PATH:/mnt/d/Users/my_name/AppData/Roaming/npm/bower`.
   **Note that a drive is accessible from `/mnt/[letter]`.**
2. Then when trying `bower` again it would tell me `/usr/bin/env: node: Not a directory`. So I created a symbolic link to "node": `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`.

It works! :)