# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined - Mean.IO

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I have followed the [steps to install](http://mean.io/#!/docs) mean.io, but when I browse the localhost:3000 I get a blank page and when I open the console I get a list of files pointing to the same error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined**

my issue is something similar [to this](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/331), but I re-installed bower and it didn't work I'm still getting the error.

I'm trying to install this in ubuntu 14.04

this is the screen I get:

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined]

Do I need to perform some sort of modification to any script, file reference or configuration, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab? Is there a 404 for angular.js or angular.min.js? Also, you say your "reinstalled bower" but what that article instructed you to do was run "bower install" (ie. run "bower" on the command line with "install" as the parameter). Which did you do?

Comment: I used bower install --allow--root, it turns out that I had blocked some urls for some bower dependencies, it's fixed for now. thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved in this way:

You need to install or reinstall "[bower](http://bower.io/)"

Check your bower.json file, it should look something like this:

```
{
"name": "mean",
"version": "0.3.0",
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-resource": "latest",
    "angular-cookies": "latest",
    "angular-mocks": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest",
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "#master"
  }
}
```

and then run the following command:

`sudo bower install --allow-root`

This will install to "Angular" in the project

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that Bower had failed to run or that my Yeoman MEAN generator hadn't run it at all. I was able to simply run "bower install" and it fixed my problem completely.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't get this this error the previous five times I installed this. I'm still unclear as to what I did incorrectly but this solved the problem at least.

Comment: I think that happens when you have installed git

Comment: I got this error after I checked out the code in a new environment and needed to install bower and run bower install. Thanks for the hlep.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but for some reason the top answer here (reinstalling bower and running `sudo bower install --allow-root`) didn't work for me.

However the answer form this stackoverflow thread worked -> [bower command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369390/bower-command-not-found#comment25814310_12369390) Basically the author there said I wasn't setting `npm prefix` properly and to fix that the following was required:

```
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower
```

Answer (score 0):

note the it is bad form to install mean.io as root and as a result run bower or npm as root.
We actually built processes into mean-clithat will disallow running as root.
Running as root is the sure way to expose mean to more serious security issues and to "contaminating" you .npm and .bower caches with a mix of normal and root based permissions which is very frustrating for "newbies"

Comment: Good point, though I would suggest moving this to a comment on the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind the proxy, then still problem not solved. So in order to solve it you need to include proxy-setting in .bowerrc file as

```
 {
  "directory": "public/lib",
  "proxy":"http://user:passwd@server:port",
  "https-proxy":"http://user:passwd@server:port"

}
```

Now run

```
sudo npm install -g bower
sudo bower install --allow-root
```

Comment: i need your help #reenu29