# bower is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have successfully installed nodejs, and express framework, however I downloaded bower via

```
npm install -g bower
```

which ran successfully.

However whenever I try to install something with bower I get the error message

```
bower is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

when I search my computer for bower or a bower.exe I cannot locate it.

Comment: OS? What command are you using to install something with Bower?

Comment: sorry I am using Windows 7, and I am using the command " bower install angular"

Comment: possible duplicate of [bower command not found windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732447/bower-command-not-found-windows)

Comment: Related post - [bower command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12369390/465053) & [Bower: “command not found” after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15846076/465053)

Answer (score 60):

I am using Windows 7 as well and had this problem too.

After I took the steps outlined in [Scott Marchant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196273/4463445), bower worked.

> Find the location of your npm global binaries: npm config get prefix. This path may look something like C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm.
>   Add the path from step 1 to your Path.
>
> Open the Windows Control Panel, search for environment, then click on either edit environment variables for your account, or Edit the system environment variables`.
>
> Find the variable named Path or PATH, or create one if it doesn't exist.
>
> Paste the path from step 1 here (; delimited).
>
> You may need to restart your command prompt window.
>
> You should now be able to enter bower commands.

Comment: It is better to use %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm when adding to the global System Path

Answer (score 55):

I solved this issue using command

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

make sure `-g` exist in command.

I am using os Window10.

Answer (score 36):

Installing Bower Windows:

1. Install Node.js (required)
2. `npm install -g bower`
3. Add to the Path environment variable for your both Systems and Users like this:

> ;C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin

4. Restart your machine
5. Open command prompt anywhere and type `bower` to verify that it works. DONE.

Comment: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin` - did not work for me.
However, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm` - did work for me. I am using a Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Worked for me :D

Answer (score 8):

1. Open cmd
2. Check bower is installed successfully:

   bower version -v
   If bower version showed then go to step 3, else execute:

   npm install -g bower
   to install bower
3. Close and re-open cmd (to apply new environment variables)
4. using CD command to navigate to folder that has bower.json file then run

   bower install
   DONE.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes even after Scott's steps do not resolve the problem. Open the command prompt in admin mode. This resolves the problem

Comment: Thanks Nagesh.. opening Command Prompt in Windows with "Run as Administrator" resolved my problem. I was able to launch bower. :)

Comment: I had the opposite problem - I had installed node under my normal user account but was running the command prompt as Administrator (instinctively!). This answer helped, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Press Window+R
2. **%appdata%** Press Enter Key
3. **C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm**
4. Double Click  **bower.cmd** icon
5. Press Shift Right Mouse Click Then Selec **Open Command Window Here**
6. Paste **bower install MDBootstrap**

SCREENSHOT
[image]

Comment: But everytime, the file closing suddenly

Answer (score 1):

Check were your cmd prompt/bash is located when you have successfully commanded "npm install"

Look for the any of the following.
-bower.cmd - windows command script
-bower     - file
you can do a quick search in the directory.

if you find it, copy the path to the file.
"I found mine in the directory where I successfully performed npm install" + node_modules.bin" - "D:\Work\notepadplusplus\htdocs\laravel-main\angulartest\public\fed\node_modules.bin"

Then do these

1. Open the Windows Control Panel
2. Go to Advance
3. Environment Variables
4. Click on either edit environment variables for your account, or Edit the system environment variables`.
5. Find the variable named Path or PATH, or create one if it doesn't exist.
6. Paste the path from your search earlier (; delimited and without any space).
7. restart your command prompt window or your bash window.

There is no specific path since we all have different structure of our directories.
The only precise thing here is to find the bower.cmd location and that will be used to the Path to your windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Although we have already good answers here, I will give an extra hint. Check if you have a .npmrc file inside the folder /Users/YOUR_USER/. When this problem happened to me, my .npmrc file had this content:

```
http_proxy=http://<LOGIN>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY>:<PORT>
https_proxy=http://<LOGIN>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY>:<PORT>
proxy=http://<LOGIN>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY>:<PORT>/
https-proxy=http://<LOGIN>:<PASSWORD>@<PROXY>:<PORT>
prefix = "D:\\<SOME_DIR>\\nodejs"
cache = "D:\\<SOME_DIR>\\nodejs\\npm-cache"
```

Due to **prefix** and **cache** lines, the bower was being installed inside the folder specified in prefix.

SOLUTION: I deleted **prefix** and **cache** lines. The I installed bower again with the following command:

```
npm install -g bower
```

After that, my bower became global as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm;`

should exist in PATH for both "User Variables" and "System Variables"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. I have solved by using the following steps

1. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System and click Advanced system settings
2. In that you can see Environment Variables in Advanced tab. Now ,Environment Variables Window opens.
3. Select the path and click Edit button and add C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm  . Click ok to save.

Note : before adding path add a colon(;) in front of that path if not there for previous one

Now you can able to install bower . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue my changing access rights of node.js folder. I gave Read-Write access to the file and issue resolved. node.js file path: C:\Program Files\nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add update to windows 10 users,
 I found that typing **bower** into the search bar will return "run command" option. Execute that and it will then prompt if bower can submit info, return a y/n and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory of bower to the PATH environment variable.
Avoid having any space between directories:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin;C:\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

To me it helped to remove the user variable and write the PATH environment variable in the System variables.

Comment: The above worked for me:                                              I added :      
                 RUN setx PATH '%PATH%;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe;C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\bower\\bin;'                                          
          to my docker file after in installing node, and all was well.