# Bower is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I know the question has been asked many times but really none of them helped me.
I'm on windows 10 and have successfully installed bower via npm using the following code

```
npm install -g bower
```

I've added the path to system environment variable but still getting the same error bower is 
not recognized as internal or external command.

I've added the following path into my system environment variable

```
C:\Users\habib\AppData\Romaing\npm
```

While when I try

```
  npm config get prefix
 C:\Users\habib\AppData\Romaing\npm
```

When I try

```
npm bower -v
```

I get the bower version

[Tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732447/bower-command-not-found-windows) as well [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360710/bower-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Neither of them worked for me.

Why is that so?

Comment: Are you sure that `bower` binary is located within `C:\Users\habib\AppData\Romaing\npm`?

Comment: @mic4ael I've checked the directory and it contains following folder

Comment: etc, node_modules,bower, bower.cmd

Comment: is `bower` a directory?

Comment: sorry nop that's not a directory but it is cmd file while node_modules is only a directory which contains another folder bower....

Comment: What is the value of your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: C:\Users\habib\AppData\Romaing\npm

Comment: @mic4ael Thank you man I just set the path in users environment  variable aswell and it worked.. between thanks for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried set the Path variable value in Users Environment variable to the same as for System Environment variable and it worked...

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 5):

I've edited the path variable in the environment variables and set it up to the following path and it has worked for me.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows users -> If even after adding the path to the environment variables , it doesnt work , try using bower through a **git bash shell instead of the windows command prompt.** . Mine worked that way.

Answer (score -2):

Set user variable `path` - C:\Program Files\Nodejs
and set system variable path - C:\Users\pk-03\AppData\Roaming\npm