# bower is not recognizable as an available command

Tags: git, npm, bower, git-bash

I install nodejs, npm, then use this command to install bower:

```
npm install -g bower
npm bower -v 
2.15.5
node -v 
v4.4.5
```

However in my Git Bash, I can't run bower:

```
$ bower
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\bower\bin\bower'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Things I have tried:

- I have tried [the solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450214/bower-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command) by adding to PATH, but still no help. Any idea why it happened and how to solve it ?
- Install bower locally: `npm install bower`.

Comment: Just to clarify, all commands like `npm install -g bower` - have you run them in `git bash`?

Comment: Try removing `C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules` - I don't think you intended to install files there, and it may be interfering with the global installation.

Comment: @Ivan : yep I ran them in `git bash`.

Comment: @Aurora0001 : exactly, `bower` should be installed under `%APPDATA%\`, I removed those files and still can't get bower to be recognizable.

Comment: What does `npm config get prefix` output?

Comment: @Aurora0001 : it's `C:\Users\Dio\AppData\Roaming\npm` .

Comment: That appears to be right. Open that up in Windows Explorer and verify that Bower is there - if not, we know that the global install didn't work at all.

Comment: `bower` and `bower.cmd` are there. I even had `%APPDATA%` in my PATH and yet it still showed error. After digging up some more, I notice my Nodejs was quite old (v4.4.5) so I went ahead and upgrade to v6.9.1 LTS. The problem is gone ! Not the best solution but it works for me.