# Install Bower Components on Windows

Tags: bower-install

I'm trying to perform the instalation of some Bower components specified on a bower.json file on Windows.

I opened the command prompt and introduced the command "bower install" on the respective folder. The problem is I received the message:

'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bower is not recognised as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360710/bower-is-not-recognised-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem.

I runned [this](http://bower.io/) in Command prompt:

`npm install -g bower`

If that does not work you need to make sure that [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) is installed before.

And make sure the following path is in the Windows PATH Environment Variable:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I had this problem when publishing an ASP.NET 5.0 -> ASP.NET Core 1.0 project, the next error was that gulp was also not found. Logically fixed with this:

`npm install -g gulp`