# Correct Way to Add Bower Location to $PATH Variable?

Tags: node.js, macos, zurb-foundation, bower, path-variables

I'm trying to install a Foundation 5 project on OS X 10.10. I have installed Bower, but when installing the Foundation project (i.e. foundation new my-project-folder), it returns:

```
Can't find bower. You can install it by running: sudo npm install -g bower
```

`locate bower` returns:

```
Users/[username]/..
.cache/..
.local/share/..
.npm/..
```

The only path currently in .bash_profile is:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

`echo $PATH` returns:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

It appears that this is insufficient for finding Bower.

Can this issue be resolved by adding:

```
PATH=/usr/local/share:$PATH
```

to .bash_profile? Is there a better approach?

Why would Bower not be findable after installing it (i.e. `npm install -g bower`)?'

It may be relevant that I just upgraded from Mountain Lion. I did so because it uses Ruby 1.8+, and Foundation requires Ruby 1.9+. I tried Homebrew while still on Mountain Lion, but this created a hot mess, so the OS upgrade seemed like the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try prefixing npm as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369390/bower-command-not-found).

`$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower`

Then check that bower shows up in your path with `$ which bower`